# Node.js - Firebase import returns a Illegal Instruction running on a Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: node.js, firebase, raspberry-pi

I tried with both server and client SDKs, and both return `Illegal Instruction`:

- with the client SDK, it only needs the `var firebase = require("firebase");` to return it;
- with the server SDK, it returns it when trying to write on a `Firestore document`.

I'm running it on a RaspberryPi Zero W, Node version is `10.9.0` and Npm version is `6.2.0`. I installed it from https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.9.0/node-v10.9.0-linux-armv6l.tar.gz

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run this command on your code folder and It will take about 10 minutes or more:

**sudo npm rebuild --build-from-source grpc**

For more detail: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/rYGlhi9nQTE

Hope this help you.

Regards,